# Insufficient privileges to operate on user

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I get error "Insufficient privileges to operate on user" when I run `drop user SNOWFLAKE`.

Is that a special user in snowflake?

Thanks

> Query ID: 0193baea-0044-27e5-0000-0f4d000f339a

Comment: the query id is only of use to snowflake support, and we are not snowflake support.

Comment: Yes, this is a special account that Snowflake Support will use (with your explicit permission) to troubleshoot issues on your account when there's no other option. You can drop or disable the user, but you have to transfer ownership permissions first. If you do decide to drop the user, please don't recreate the user so that Snowflake Support has a fallback option to recreate it themselves as needed (if that kind of troubleshooting via your account login is necessary).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have disabled, and dropped support users in the past, but the long and short of it is, they have quite tight protocols over accessing customer accounts. And if they need to access your account they just create new accounts. So it is not like "you can keep them out", they are running the matrix as such..

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a system user, yes. If you run SHOW USERS you'll see that it was created at the time when your snowflake environment was set up, and that the user has no password and has probably never been logged in. Also, you cannot user DESCRIBE USER for this user as with normal user defined users.